# Add Login History section on landing Home Page

Tags: home-page-component, home-page-layout, login-history

How can I add Login History section to the Home page(landing page) to track the login history and login time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can create a report with a chart from `User` object. Group rows by `Login Date` and for columns use `Login status`, `Full Name`, `Login Date/Time` and others you need. Add it on the Home lightning page. On the page, it will display only a chart and you will have to click into `View Report` to see more. See example of such report below.
   [image]
2. You can create a custom LWC or Aura component and put it on the Home page.

Don't forget that you need to have the `Manage users` access in order to see the login history.

Comment: thank you for your response, let me try this out.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the 1st option you mentioned?

Comment: @DebabrataJena I updated the answer, I had the wrong object there. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: how would create a report using User object?

Comment: see this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328233&type=1&mode=1

Comment: i'm really very thankful to you till the report making thing but now will you please guide me through adding the report created to my Home page. How would i do that?

Comment: I recommend to use Google :) https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h64zAAA